# How to change the font size of element without disrupting any spacing?

Tags: html, css

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  left: 490px;
  top: 100px;
  background-color: #66ff66;
  width: 400px;
}
input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  border: none;
}
table {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'Orbitron';
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: all;
  justify-content: center;
}
td {
  padding: 22px 22px;
  text-align: center;
}
td:hover {
  animation-name: animate;
  animation-duration: 0.2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
@keyframes animate {
  0% {color: #ff9900; font-size: 45px;}
  25% {color: #ff0000;}
  50% {color: #66ffcc;}
  75% {color: #3399ff;}
  100% {color: #6600ff;}
}
#td-0 {
  position: relative;
  left: 125px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Calculator</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Orbitron" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="container">
        <input type="text" name="screen" disabled>
        <table class="calc-buttons">
          <tr class="row-1">
            <td>C</td>
            <td>CE</td>
            <td><i class="fas fa-long-arrow-alt-left"></i></td>
            <td>/</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="row-2">
            <td>9</td>
            <td>8</td>
            <td>7</td>
            <td>*</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="row-3">
            <td>6</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>-</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="row-4">
            <td>3</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>+</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="row-5">
            <td id="td-0">0</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Hey guys I'm styling a calculator and I'm trying to change the font size of each button when hovering. Is there a way to do this so the character on the button or the td element will change size independently of its container. So it doesn't push everything out of the way? Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks guys.

Comment: Just make the height and width of the `td` bigger so the character doesn't do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the `padding` smaller on hover, so it would "cancel" the greater `font-size`. So because the change in the `font-size` is 5 pixels, where you change the `font-size` I've added `padding: 17px` (5 pixels less than the initial `padding` - `22px`).
That's in the code snippet.
Another thing you can do is to use `scale transform` that enlarges the element without affecting other elements positioning.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  left: 490px;
  top: 100px;
  background-color: #66ff66;
  width: 400px;
}
input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  border: none;
}
table {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'Orbitron';
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: all;
  justify-content: center;
}
td {
  padding: 22px 22px;
  text-align: center;
}
td:hover {
  animation-name: animate;
  animation-duration: 0.2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;

}
@keyframes animate {
  0% {color: #ff9900; font-size: 45px; padding: 17px;}
  25% {color: #ff0000;}
  50% {color: #66ffcc;}
  75% {color: #3399ff;}
  100% {color: #6600ff;}
}
#td-0 {
  position: relative;
  left: 125px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Calculator</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Orbitron" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <input type="text" name="screen" disabled>
      <table class="calc-buttons">
        <tr class="row-1">
          <td>C</td>
          <td>CE</td>
          <td><i class="fas fa-long-arrow-alt-left"></i></td>
          <td>/</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row-2">
          <td>9</td>
          <td>8</td>
          <td>7</td>
          <td>*</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row-3">
          <td>6</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row-4">
          <td>3</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>+</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row-5">
          <td id="td-0">0</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
 </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

what about adding  to make the font doesn't get out from your space?